# Gmail API Connection

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I have been trying to send a test email via the Gmail API configuration with little success. I am not sure what is wrong exactly, but the error I am receiving is as follows:

> File "c:\Development\foodSaver\emailAPI.py", line 20, in send_message
> message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'users'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Development\foodSaver\emailAPI.py", line 28, in 
> send_message('Gmail', 'Person','yes')   File "c:\Development\foodSaver\emailAPI.py", line 23, in send_message
> except errors.HttpError as error: NameError: name 'errors' is not defined

I have put the Credentials.json file in the same directory as my project, but was never asked to reference it in this script.

The code I have so far (that is producing this error):

```
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64
import os

# Writes gmail message 
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  message = message.as_string()
  message = message.encode('utf-8')
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message)}

# Sends gmail message 
def send_message(service, user_id, message):
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)

create_message('abittar@nyit.edu','abittar@nyit.edu','This is a test email.','This is the test body message.')
send_message('Gmail', 'Person','yes')
```

For the last part I tried inputting random things for the def variables in order to test.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second errors occur when you pass the wrong arguments in your send_message function. The content of `service` should be resource object and the content of `user_id` should be an email or 'me'.

You need to create credentials and use it to construct a resource to interact with Gmail API. You can start by following this [Python Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) on how to setup your credentials and install necessary libraries. Once you're done with setup, your code should look like this:

Note: You can copy and paste the code and replace the sender and recipient email. Make sure that the content of `credentials.json` is on the same level as your main script. In my example below, I used [this](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#desktop) to obtain the content of credentials.json

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64
import os

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']


# Writes gmail message
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}


# Sends gmail message
def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    msg = create_message('sender email', 'recipient email', 'This is a test email.',
                         'This is the test body message.')
    send_message(service, 'me', msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```